# Gradle, parallel task execution

Tags: java, spring, gradle, parallel-processing

I've got a project that containt two projects - frontend and backend.
I want be able to run these two projects with one command, in parallel. 
I've created task like below

```
    task bootFullApplication(type: GradleBuild) {
  group 'application'
    setTasks(['npm_install','frontend:npm_run_startDev'])
    setTasks(['backend:build', 'backend:adminBoot'])}
```

Is it possible to run this task in parallel? How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this approach was a mistake. If you want do run angular app along with spring app just copy what's angular produce to your backend app and it will be fine.